# Ansible loops throught inventory

Tags: loops, ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm looking for a way to loop on ansible inventory

inventory

```
[deployer]
ceph-node0

[mons]
ceph-node0
ceph-node1
ceph-node2
```

task.yml

```
- hosts: deployer
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: create monitor node
      command: ceph orch apply mon {{ item.0 }},{{ item.1 }},{{ item.2 }}, {{ itemN }}
      with_items: 
        - "{{ groups['mons'] }}"
```

I expect results like this with only one execution

```
ceph orch apply mon ceph-node0,ceph-node1,ceph-node2,..ceph-nodeN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`join`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) filter.

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "ceph orch apply mon {{ groups['mons'] | join(',') }}"
```